# What type of diagram could this be?

Tags: notation, visualization

Some years ago, I saw a diagram somewhat like this somewhere on Wikipedia.

[image]

I remember that it was supposedly used in some branch of mathematics. Unfortunately, neither Google Image nor trawling Wikimedia Commons has turned up any useful results.

To what type of diagram could a symbol like this belong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation ?

Comment: @Rahul You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.